# How to return html code as a variable in python

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I try to return html code as variable.
What am I doing wrong?

python:
`return render_template("dashboard.html", services = "<h1>Service 1</h1>")`
html:
`Your services: {{services}}`

But it gives the services value as text:
`Your services: <h1>Service 1</h1>"`

Answer (score 0):

Seems your Jinja2 is in automatic escaping mode. You need to mark your string as "safe" so that it won't be escaped:

```
{{services|safe}}
```

Read more at [Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#html-escaping).